# How can I show a relationed fields at the end of a Custom Post Type content in a Genesis Child Theme

Tags: php

I am trying to show a list of relationed posts through a custom field (which I've created using Advanced Custom Fields, by the way). I am using genesis Framework and a child theme (of course). The custom Field is a relationship field and it is called "lecciones_relacionadas". I've marked it as an object, too.

I have a Custom Post Type called "lecciones" (which I created with CPT UI plugin. At the end of every "lecciones" I'd like a list with all the other relationed lecciones.

I've created this snippet and attached at the end of the functions.php, but it doesn't work.

add_action ( 'genesis_after_entry_content' , 'completar_lecciones' );

function completar_lecciones() {

```
if (is_singular ('lecciones')) {

the_field('lecciones_relacionadas');

}
```

}